# store in instance variable, each block results ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.1

This sentence `b.followees_by_type("biscuit")` return something like:

```
=> [#<Biscuit _id: 4fdf5aa11d41c829ea000020, _type: "Biscuit", created_at: 2012-06-18 16:43:13 UTC, title: "biscuit biscuit", is_complete: true>, #<Biscuit _id: 4fdf5aa11d41c829ea000021, _type: "Biscuit", created_at: 2012-06-18 17:40:10 UTC, title: "biscuit2 biscuit2", is_complete: true> ]
```

**Can return one or more biscuits.**

I want add inside a instance variable `@biscuits`, all biscuits I get in each loop from this block:

```
boards.each do |b| 
  b.followees_by_type("biscuit")
end
```

How can I do it?

Comment: So do it. What's stopping you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [Enumerable#flat_map](http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Enumerable.html#method-i-flat_map):

```
@biscuits = boards.flat_map {|b| b.followees_by_type('biscuit') }
```